# Slide view upon TextField selection is only on typing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uikeyboard

I have used the demonstration code Apple has in their docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

I need to slide the view up when the keyboard appears from tapping a UITextField. I am using the code in the link above, Apple's own demo code for ding this and it makes sense.

However, my issue, using Apple's code virtually unchanged, the view only slides up when typing, vs actually after tapping on the text field.

In the `- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification` method, it is when this if statement is called that the view is slid up or not. Slid up if the textfield is below the keyboard, not slid up if it isn't below the keyboard.

```
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
```

Trouble is, upon tapping the text field, this if statement is skipped, the code inside it doesn't run.

I can't work it out, but it all happens in this method below. Why is it only sliding up on typing and not the initial tap?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your application might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add the code in listing 4-2 on that apple doc?  so that active field is set?

Comment: Yep, I've added all code required for this to supposedly work, as listed by Apple.

Comment: Can you do a little NSLogging near the scene of the crime?  Would like to see aRect and activeField.frame before the condition is checked.  It's pretty surprising that apple publishes this yuckiness:  What if the text field origin lies just above the top of the keyboard?  Also, it's quite a lot of hoop jumping to find the first responder, how about a quick search thru the view hierarchy instead?

Comment: aRect: `{{0, 0}, {320, 332}}`
activeTextField Frame: `{{15, 7}, {250, 30}}`

Comment: So, surely this is impossible to work as it is, as at this point (immediately before the if statement), the keyboard bounds are 0, 0. Meaning no other subview can be underneath it (or in that area). How on earth do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked again at the Apple doc.  Yuck - don't they write software for a living??  Try this instead:  Remember the default position of the main view.

```
@interface ViewController ()
    @property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat viewOriginY;
@end
```

Register for keyboard notification and a tap (to dismiss first responder).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.viewOriginY = self.view.frame.origin.y;

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    // add a tap gesture to drop first responder
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
}
```

Write a function to (recursively) find the first responder.

```
- (UIView *)firstResponderWithin:(UIView *)view {

    if ([view isFirstResponder]) return view;

    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        UIView *answer = [self firstResponderWithin:subview];
        if (answer) return answer;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here's the punchline:  When the keyboard is shown, compute it's frame and the frame of the view that needs to be visible.  Important to do this in a common coordinate system, like this vc's view.  Then slide the view to make the first responder visible.

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    CGRect keyboardFrameW = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [window convertRect:keyboardFrameW toView:self.view];

    UIView *firstResponder = [self firstResponderWithin:self.view];
    CGRect firstResponderFrame = [firstResponder.superview convertRect:firstResponder.frame toView:self.view];

    // let's put the bottom of the first responder's frame just above the top of the keyboard
    CGFloat firstResponderBottom = CGRectGetMaxY(firstResponderFrame);
    CGFloat targetBottom = keyboardFrame.origin.y - 8.0;    
    CGFloat offsetY = MAX(0.0, firstResponderBottom - targetBottom);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0.0, -offsetY);
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.viewOriginY, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

Optional - When user taps anyplace else, dismiss the keyboard.

```
- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    UIView *firstResponder = [self firstResponderWithin:self.view];
    [firstResponder resignFirstResponder];
}
```

[Working project can be found here.](https://anonfiles.com/file/985d29ea8a0cb7fddbdc2a1f3c952b04)

I think this idea is one ivar away from a nice category on view controller.  You could import it, and invoke the setup on viewDidLoad.  All it needs is a way to get the main view's default y origin without writing it in an ivar.  I need to noodle on that.

Comment: Ahh wow, this works like a dream (almost)! Only issue is, when returning the view to its original y position, it forgets the status bar, so deducting 20 pixels fixes this (status bar height), but can you think of a better way? Otherwise, great.

Comment: Yeah, hmm... that's why I added that viewOriginY  ivar to make sure the original view offset was restored.  Did you grab the code before I made that edit?

Comment: Nope, got the newest code. Its not a huge deal, but just a little mystery.

Comment: When I run it, viewOriginY gets initialized to 20.0, and the view gets restored to that on keyboardWillHide:.  Is it doing something else for you?